# TFS code access with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I and my friend want to work in a common codebase. I found Visual studio Team Services matching my needs. i could check-in the project.  Visual Studio Team Services seems to have 5 free basic licenses. So, I added my friend as basic user. However, he is not able to access the code.

we are looking for free access.

Can someone please guide me on this? If it is not free, are there any other TFS-like online services available?

Comment: Can you add more details? It is a login error, a permission error? Can he navigate your project?

Comment: No, he is not able to navigate to project. He is trying to access the project url which he recieved via email when i added him to the project.He is redirected to the page which says "Sorry, but XXX<XXXXX@XXXX.com> (Microsoft Account) is not authorized to access this page"

Comment: Try adding his account as Team member

Comment: about the licensing question, you can refer to [visual studio online licensing page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-pricing-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not only do you have to add a users account into the correct license group, you Also need to add them with permission to each team project.

Once you have added them to the "Users" page you should navigate to your team and as then as a member.

This will give them access.